# Fetch JSON Data from URL and Repeatedly Update SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, http

In my app, I create a SQLite database. Then I populate it with JSON data fetched from a URL using an instance of the HttpAsyncTask class in my main activity. That works fine, but I also want to update the database. New data (one row in the database) is added to the URL page once per day, and I want to implement a "synchronize" button in the app that updates the database with only the new information. Could I get some advice on how to do this? My HttpAsyncTask is below, if that helps - I'm thinking I might need an if/else clause in the onPostExecute() method that adds all the rows only if the database is getting created for the first time. I thought about trying to put an HttpAsyncTask class in my DatabaseHelper, but that doesn't really make sense.

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...urls) {
        return GET(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject main = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject body = main.getJSONObject("body");
            JSONArray measuregrps = body.getJSONArray("measuregrps");

            // get measurements for date, unit, and value (weight)
            for (int i = 0; i < measuregrps.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject row = measuregrps.getJSONObject(i);
               // a lot of getting & parsing data happens
               db.addEntry(new Entry(date, weight, null, null)); 
               //adds all the lines every time this is run, but I only want to add all 
               //the lines once and then add new rows one by one from there
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static String GET(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(get);
        is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if (is != null)
            result = convertInputStream(is);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("input stream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        builder.append(line);
    is.close();
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation totally depends on the project requirements.
If there are continuously changes over the server, the right way to implement the synchronization process is:

1.
Implement the sync process, which works totally in background. This sync will be customized to call specific API calls/Service classes which will be required to sync.

2.
Server will prompt the mobile client for the data change.

3.
To get server updates, A continuously running service/Sync at some predefined intervals will be run and checks for the updates or implements the GCM.

Sync Adapter would be the best for the sync services.
Ohh, also don't forget to apply the content provider, as database calls would be concurrent from UI and background both.

Hope it may help to decide.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said continually. I only want to fetch new data & update the database when the user presses the "sync" button. I feel like it should be easy - if the website has two more lines of data than the number of rows in my database, add two rows of the most recent data. I'm just not sure where to put that code.

Comment: Create the Service class under Infra, call as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check there is similar data available in the table if yes update the table and if no insert new data to table